# How to store a timestamp in Oracle that occurs within the hour skipped at the start of Daylight Savings

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, dst

Our Oracle server is running in Australia/Sydney time.

We plan to store some new dates in UTC.

For example, one of the dates we may store is **5 Oct 2014 2:00AM**.

However in Sydney we have Daylight Savings start at the same time, which means that times from **2:00AM** to **2:59AM** do not exist on that day.

For example, on **5 Oct 2014** the times that occur are:

01:58
01:59
03:00
03:01

The trouble is that if I try to store the time `2014-10-05 02:00` in the database, it's silently converted to `2014-10-05 03:00`

We don't have the option to change the timezone on the server, so is there any way to store `2014-10-05 02:00` in our database?

**Edit for comment from @mrjoltcola**

Our server is running with timezone setting **(GMT +10) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney**

If I run the command `select DBTIMEZONE from dual;` the output is the single value `+00:00` (this was unexpected).

Our original column was a **TIMESTAMP** only column and I did not supply any timezone details with the insert.

For further exploration I created a test table as follows:

```
create table TEST
(
  ID number,
  TS timestamp,
  TS_TZ timestamp with time zone
)
```

I then run the following insert statements (with and without the timezone):

```
insert into TEST
VALUES
(
  1,
  TIMESTAMP '2014-10-05 02:00:00 UTC',
  TIMESTAMP '2014-10-05 02:00:00 UTC'
);

insert into TEST
VALUES
(
  2,
  TIMESTAMP '2014-10-05 02:00:00',
  TIMESTAMP '2014-10-05 02:00:00'
);
```

Which produces the result:

```
+---+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | 05/OCT/14 03:00:00.000000000 AM | 05/OCT/14 02:00:00.000000000 AM UTC              |
+---+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 05/OCT/14 03:00:00.000000000 AM | 05/OCT/14 03:00:00.000000000 AM AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY |
+---+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the column type? Is it a plain TIMESTAMP or perhaps a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE?

Comment: @mrjoltcola the column is a plain TIMESTAMP. This is a new field we're adding so I've just changed it to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE and it seems to have solved the issue. Would you like to provide this comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer? Many thanks.

Comment: Ill be glad to as soon as I figure out just what is going on. Im still confused by how your original timestamps were being adjusted if you were storing them in UTC. If you can tell me what the timezone setting of your Oracle database is, and the before and after SQL you used to insert, it will help. Are you specifying timezone in the insert?

Comment: I've edited the original question to provide some more details. Initially I just had a TIMESTAMP field with an insert that did not provide the timezone. Now I am using a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE field and am providing the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

> > The trouble is that if I try to store the time 2014-10-05 02:00 in the database, it's silently converted to 2014-10-05 03:00

On my database, I can set the session timezone to 'Australia/Sydney' and still store 2014-10-05 02:00:00 in a plain TIMESTAMP column without having it converted. But if I change it to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE and try to store the same value, I get ***ORA-01878***

So I don't think your time was being converted to 03:00:00 based on Oracle trying to adjust the daylight savings, I think you are supposed to receive an ***ORA-01878*** when you specify an incorrect timestamp. Instead, I think your client/session timezone was mismatching your database/server timezone by an hour, and you were seeing normal Oracle adjustment.

Oracle will convert timestamps when the client/session timezone mismatches the server/database timezone. Since there is no timezone info in a regular TIMESTAMP field, Oracle won't mind storing it.

So your "silently converted to 2014-10-05 03:00" should have been happening for other time values (did you try inserting 01:00 and see if it resulted in an adjustment and/or an ORA-01878 error?).

When I try here by setting my session timezone to Australia/Sydney and insert that time, I get:

```
SQL> alter session set time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into test(ts) values(1, timestamp '2014-10-05 02:00:00');
insert into test values(1, timestamp '2014-10-05 02:00:00')

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test(ts_tz) values(2, timestamp '2014-10-05 02:00:00');
insert into test(ts_tz) values(2, timestamp '2014-10-05 02:00:00')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
```

Now, as to your question, if you want to store UTC time, you should either explicitly specify timestamps with UTC, or set your database or session timezone to UTC. You don't have to have DBA privs to set the session time_zone, and it can differ from the db time_zone.

```
SQL> alter session set time_zone = '+00:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select dbtimezone, sessiontimezone from dual;

DBTIME SESSIONTIMEZONE
------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00:00 +00:00
SQL> insert into test values(1, timestamp '2014-10-05 02:00:00');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID TS
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 05-OCT-14 02.00.00.000000 AM
```

However, the above TIMESTAMP field isn't necessarily UTC. It could change if the DB server timezone changed. To Oracle a plain TIMESTAMP is just a timestamp with no timezone information. If you want UTC time, but may be dealing with clients in different timezones, you can use TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the detailed answer. Based on your notes I've been able to make some progress. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. When the value in the db is "05/OCT/2014 02:00" it displays in SQL Dev as "05/OCT/2014 03:00", however using TO_CHAR(ts,'HH24') always displays 02 for the hour. I think this is a Java issue - either in SQL Dev or the JDBC driver. My computer's timezone is Australia/Sydney timezone which I believe results in Java performing these silent date conversions within SQL Developer. When I set my computer's timezone to something else then the times display correctly.

Comment: I'm considering that we just go with a TIMESTAMP field rather than a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE for a couple of reasons: (1) we will only store UTC, so timezone is effectively redundant, (2) I get the impression that TIMEZONE fields are not impacted by the session timezone, so we would not need to have any special handling for that, and (3) I suspect it also means that ORA-01878 should never occur. Would appreciate any thoughts you have?

Comment: I'll research it more tomorrow with SQL Developer. I think there is conversion going on between the server and the client, for sure. To actually figure this out I may need a server set to Australia/Sydney as well. If I get time tomorrow I'll set one of mine as such. Are you running SQL Developer on another PC or directly on the server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Developer is on a separate machine from the server. Many thanks.

Comment: Actually, a quick test would be to just store the date 2014-10-05 02:00:00 in a TIMESTAMP column, change your PC to the Sydney timezone, start up SQL Developer and view that date. I'm guessing you will see the same behaviour.